# In Ruby on Rails, how can you use vanity URLs and also redirect to 404s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vanity-url

At the end of my routes.rb, I have a wildcard match for vanity urls.  However, I can't figure out how to redirect unknown usernames to a 404.  How can you do this?

~ in routes.rb ~

```
# Vanity URLs
match ':username', :to => "users#show"
```

~ in the users controller ~

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
if @user.nil?
  render :status => 404
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: What part of this isn't working for you?

Comment: It just didn't redirect at all.  As jdeseno answered, it was still rendering the default template with a 404 response code.  You have to use the code jdeseno provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have will still render the default template but, with a 404 response code.

Try this to render the default 404 page instead:

```
render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :layout => false, :status => 404
```